# Jquery change prev() input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so i am trying to change the value of an input field by using jquery's prev() function.  I have a text field with some links after it.  When someone clicks on the link i want it to change the previous

```
<label>
    <input type="text"/>
</label>

<ul>
  <li onclick="field('name1','value1');"><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li onclick="field('name2','value2');"><a href="#">link2</a></li>  
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function field($name,$value){
     $(this).prev("input").attr('name','$name');
     $(this).prev("input").attr('value','$value');
}
</script>
```

i think you can see what i am trying to do.  I want them person to click a link and it change the value and name attributes of the text field and obviously display the new value inside the the text box.  I want to use "this" so that i can use this anywhere instead of specifying a id or class.  I think im close but haven't gotten it to work yet.  Am i using the correct jquery script or should i be using something different?  Thanks.

Comment: jQuery is not PHP.  You don't *need* the `$` before variables (`$` is just part of a variable name, you can have it, if you want).  `'$name'` is just the literal string `'$name'`.  If you want the variable, just use its name, no quotes.  `.attr('name', $name);`  Also, to change an input's value, use `.val()`.  `.val($value)`.

Comment: Can you post your actual html structure? I have a feeling there is a much better way of organizing your data so that your javascript code will be more robust. Also, avoid declaring onclick inline. Use jquery's `$(selector).click()` method instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `.prev()` here because the input is not an "immediately preceding sibling" ([see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/prev/#prev1))

If you really want to go this route you'd have to do something like this....

```
<label>
  <input type="text"/>
</label>

<ul>
  <li onclick="field(this,'name1','value1');"><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li onclick="field(this,'name2','value2');"><a href="#">link2</a></li>  
</ul>


<script>
function field(el, $name,$value){
  $(el).closest("ul").prev("label").find("input").attr({
    name : $name,
    value : $value
  });
}
</script>
```

There are a few things I don't like about this....

1. You're using inline Javascript
2. Relying on a very specific HTML structure like this isn't always the best choice because you may change the structure of your html later and not realize that you need to update the function accordingly.

Not knowing the overall structure of your entire page, I would offer this alternative approach.

```
<div class='dynamic-field'>
  <label><input type="text" /></label>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" data-name="name1" data-value="value1">link1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-name="name2" data-value="value2">link1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(".dynamic-field a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    link.closest(".dynamic-field")
        .find("input")
            .attr("name", link.data("name"))
            .val(link.data("value"));
  });
</script>
```

This has several benefits

1. You aren't using inline javascript
2. You can have several instances of this sort of dynamic field on the same page (not sure if you need this or not)
3. It is a lot less brittle. For example you could switch the `<ul>` to an `<ol>` if you wanted... or you could nest the `<a>` elements several levels deep and the code wouldn't have to change.

Comment: +1 and the poor little demo I was hashing together: http://jsfiddle.net/LFqCY/ :P

Comment: `this` will be `window` here.  When using inline JavaScript, you need to either pass `this` (`field(this, 'name1', 'value1')`), or use `.call` (`field.call(this, 'name1', value1')`).

Comment: @Rocket, you're right about `this`, I have updated my example.

Comment: good solution.  another simple option http://jsbin.com/afovus/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using inline JavaScript, you have to pass `this` explicitly:

```
<label>
    <input type="text"/>
</label>
<ul>
  <li onclick="field(this,'name1','value1');"><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li onclick="field(this,'name2','value2');"><a href="#">link2</a></li>  
</ul>
```

And then use jQuery DOM traversal which goes up and over a couple of levels, since `.prev` only looks for siblings:

```
function field(el, $name, $value) {
    $(el).closest("ul").prev("label").find("input").attr('name', $name).val($value);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JbpYn/

That said, here's a much more "jQuery" way to do the same thing that avoids inline JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input id="ip" type="text"/>
</label>

<ul id="clickme">
  <li><a href="#" data-name="name1" data-val="value1">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-name="name2" data-val="value2">link2</a></li>  
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#clickme').on('click', 'a', function(e) { // requires jQuery 1.7+
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var val = $(this).data('val');
    $('#ip').attr('name', name).val(val);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JbpYn/8/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, not using inline JavaScript, and instead using jQuery to bind the event.  It's easier to debug, and `this` will be the correct element (not `window`).  As for the paramers, you can use `data` attributes to save them.

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="toggleInput" data-name="name1" data-value="value1" ><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li class="toggleInput" data-name="name2" data-value="value2"><a href="#">link2</a></li>  
</ul>
```

And then with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('li.toggleInput').click(function(){
        var name = $(this).data('name'),
        value = $(this).data('value');

        $(this).prev("input").attr('name', name);
        $(this).prev("input").attr('value', value);
    });
});
```

In the case of your HTML, `$(this).prev("input")` won't work.  `prev` only gets the sibling before, not an element that happens to be before it in the HTML.  You'll have to do a little traversing to get the element you want.  Such as:

```
$(this).closest("ul").prev("label").find("input")
```

If you ever change the HTML, this may break.  I suggest adding an ID (or a class) to the input, so you can quickly find it.

```
<label>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" />
</label>
```

So, now you can do:

```
$(function(){
    $('li.toggleInput').click(function(){
        var name = $(this).data('name'),
        value = $(this).data('value');

        $('#myInput').attr('name', name).val(value);
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sLXv3/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need prev() only to make it ? I have much easier solution over this. Test the html below:

```
<html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("li a").click(function(){
         var tmp=$(this).attr('id');
         $("input").attr({'name':'$name'+tmp,'value':'$value'+tmp});
    });
 });        
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label>
    <input type="text"/>
</label>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="1">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="2">link2</a></li>  
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("input")` will target *all* inputs on the page (I assume there's more than one).  Also, an ID that starts with (or is) a number is invalid.  I also think he wanted the name to be `'name1'`, not `'$name1'`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct ! for 2nd pt, need to use $(this).closest("ul").prev("label").find("input"). correct ?

Comment: Yeah, that would get the input.  I'm not sure if he has more than one input or not, but I figured I'd point that out.